# File downloaded from aws is all in question marks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I downloaded a file from aws bucket and all the text are in question marks. I am new to aws so I don't know if I need to configure something beforehand to download the file? Perhaps the file is in unicode but when I download it, it is not properly encoding.

I am using aws command line to download this file:

```
aws s3 ls s3:/directory mydirectory --recursive
```

Comment: It sounds like a binary (non-text) file. What is the extension or filetype of the file? How was it uploaded originally? Please edit your question and add these details.

Comment: Some problems here: `aws s3 ls` doesn't download anything from AWS (it lists objects in a bucket), `s3:/directory` is neither a valid bucket name nor a valid S3 URN, and `aws s3 ls` doesn't accept a folder parameter in the way that you've indicated `mydirectory`. For help with the awscli's S3 features, run `aws s3 help` or for help on uploading/downloading files, run `aws s3 cp help`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the files or directories stored as object in S3 using

- aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/test.txt test2.txt

Or

- aws s3 cp s3://mybucket . --recursive

Please refer to S3 reference guide for details here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html
Thanks!